# RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.FloatTensor but found type torch.cuda.DoubleTensor for argument #2 'weight'

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, torch

I have been trying to retrain a model but unfortunately the last 2 days I keep getting the same error.

Could you please help a little bit with this one?

**Initial work:**

```
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

import torch
from torch import nn
from torch import optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import torchvision.models as models
from collections import OrderedDict
```

**Datasets:**

```
data_dir = 'flowers'
train_dir = data_dir + '/train'

data_dir = 'flowers'

train_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(224),
                                       transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
                                       transforms.RandomRotation(45),
                                       transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                       transforms.ToTensor(),
                                       transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], 
                                                            [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])


train_data = datasets.ImageFolder(train_dir, transform=train_transforms)

trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)

import json

with open('cat_to_name.json', 'r') as f:
    cat_to_name = json.load(f)
```

**Tried to use a pretrained model and train only the classifier:**

```
# Load a pretrained model
model = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)

# Keep the parameters the same
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False


# and final output 102, since tht we have 102 flowers. 
classifier = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([            
                          ('fc1', nn.Linear(25088, 4096)), 
                          ('relu', nn.ReLU()),
                          ('fc3', nn.Linear(4096, 102)),
                          ('output', nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1))
                          ]))

# Replace model's old classifier with the new classifier
model.classifier = classifier

# Calculate the loss
criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.classifier.parameters(), lr=0.001)

model.to('cuda')

epochs = 1
print_every = 40
steps = 0

for e in range(epochs):
    running_loss = 0
    model.train()
   # model = model.double()
    for images, labels in iter(trainloader):
        steps += 1

        images.resize_(32, 3, 224, 224)          

        inputs = Variable(images.to('cuda'))
        targets = Variable(labels.to('cuda'))

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Forward and backward passes
        output = model.forward(images)
        loss = criterion(output, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        #running_loss += loss.data[0]
        running_loss += loss.item()

        if steps % print_every == 0:
            print("Epoch: {}/{}... ".format(e+1, epochs),
                  "Loss: {:.4f}".format(running_loss/print_every))
```

**Error message:**

> RuntimeError: Expected object of type `torch.FloatTensor` but found type `torch.cuda.DoubleTensor` for argument #2 `weight`

Comment: can you give more info on the traceback?

Comment: I added the whole code. Does this help?

Comment: No, on what line does the code break?

Comment: can you specifically assign ` model = model.to'cuda'`

Comment: I will try this now.

Comment: Now I got this error:
AssertionError: 
Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you
have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from

Should I use only CPU? Is there any other solution to this?

Comment: remove all your `to.cuda'` commands

Comment: I replaced:
inputs = Variable(images.to('cuda')) targets = Variable(labels.to('cuda'))

with:
 inputs = Variable(images)
 targets = Variable(labels)
I ran the script but still I have not gotten any result.

Comment: unfortunately, i got the initial error message.
# Forward and backward passes
---> 60         output = model.forward(images)

Comment: Your getting the same error `RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.FloatTensor but found type torch.cuda.DoubleTensor for argument #2 'weight'` ?

Comment: why are you using `model.to('cuda')` instead of `model.cuda()`?

Comment: Thanks for the support guys. I used the model.cuda() but i got the following error:
RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.FloatTensor but found type torch.cuda.FloatTensor for argument #2 'weight'

Comment: Hey, I am getting a similar issue, were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

---

> you should have passed inputs to the feed forward network but you have passed images to the network

---

```
# Forward and backward passes
output = model.forward(inputs)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to work with gpu in pyTorch, you have to make sure **both** the **operation-flow** (which is your model) and **data** are transferred to cuda device.
2. By this (**1**) I mean, the **whole work-flow** including `pre-trained model`, **`criterion`**, **`classifier`** and `inputs` shall all be assigned to cuda device.
3. If **(2)** is not guaranteed simply by `model.cuda()`, it might be necessary to do it manually to all objects, in order **to ensure both the internal weights and input-data are of cuda float type**.

hope it helps.